# Php: json to constants

Tags: php, eval, constants

I have a Json that contains a few contants I'd like to auto-define. It works fine with simple `"key": "val"` statements, but I can't make it work for `eval` staments:

```
$cat test.php
<?php

function objDefinition($obj) {
    foreach ($obj as $key => $val) {
        $val = $val;
        \define($key, $val);
    } }


$json = \json_decode(\json_encode([
'COOKIE_EXP' => "eval('time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60)')",
]));

objDefinition($json);
echo COOKIE_EXP;

$php test.php
eval('time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60)')
```

I know that `eval` is evil and so on, but this method would save me a lot of code!

Thanks!

Comment: json is for static values only. it cannot contain expressions as anything other than plaintext strings. so yes, the only way you could do this is via eval()

Comment: Are you getting any error? Can you provide it?

Comment: @MarcB ok, but `eval` is not working as well... putting the `eval` inside $val, I'd expect `define` to properly work: instead `COOKIE_EXP` value is `eval('time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60)')`...

Comment: @taxicala no erros, but `COOKIE_EXP` value is `eval('time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60)')`, while i'd expect something like `1747073549`...

Comment: yes, but you're not CALLING eval(). you're just defining a string that contains some text with the letters `e`, `v`, `a`, etc....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@taxicala

You almost got it:

```
function objDefinition($obj)
{
    foreach ($obj as $key => $val) {
        if (strstr($val, 'eval=')) {
            $val = str_replace('eval=', '', $val);
            eval("\$val = $val;");
        }
        \define($key, $val);
    }
}


$json = \json_decode(\json_encode([
    'COOKIE_EXP' => "eval=time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60)",
]));

\objDefinition($json);
echo COOKIE_EXP;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change a bit your data structure and your method, something like this should do the trick:

```
    function objDefinition($obj) {
        foreach ($obj as $key => $val) {
            if (strstr($val, 'eval=')) {
                \define($key, eval(str_replace('eval=', '', $val)));
            } else {
                \define($key, $val);
            }
        }
    }


    $json = \json_decode(\json_encode([
        'COOKIE_EXP' => "eval=time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60)",
    ]));
```

Comment: thanks, but it does not work: `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file in test.php(10) : eval()'d code on line 1`